# How would I add spaces in Discord application command names (slash commands)? [nextcord/discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I'm trying to create a command "/channellink" that links messages between text channels. The command has three options: "initiate", "terminate" and "list", but I can't seem to figure out how I'd add spaces to the command like "/channellink list". I can't add the options as choice arguments for "/channellink" because each of the 3 options has different choice arguments.

[I've seen other bots like Dyno use non-choice app command options with spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWlri.png), but I can't seem to figure out how it's done (attempting to add spaces to the command name throws "String value did not match validation regex.").

Comment: That's called grouping/sub-commanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slash commands with spaces are actually [subcommands](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#subcommands-and-subcommand-groups).
According to the [nextcord documentation](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/interactions.html#subcommands), subcommands can be implemented like this:

```py
from nextcord import Interaction, slash_command
from nextcord.ext.commands import Bot
from nextcord.ext.commands import Cog

class MyCog(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @slash_command(guild_ids=[...])
    async def channellink(self, interaction: Interaction):
        # Will never be executed as it contains subcommands
        pass
    
    @channellink.subcommand
    async def initiate(self, interaction: Interaction):
        pass
    
    @channellink.subcommand
    async def initiate(self, interaction: Interaction):
        pass

    @channellink.subcommand
    async def list(self, interaction: Interaction):
        pass

def setup(bot: Bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not exactly what you are looking for but a super simple way to do it would be like this:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="channellink", description='select between "initiate", "terminate" and "list"')
async def channellink(interaction: discord.Interaction, type: str):
    if type == "initiate":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Do your initiation")
    if type == "terminate":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Do your termination")
    if type == "list":
        await interaction.response.send_message("Do your list stuff")
```

**You would see it like this:**

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odcP9.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0bOg.png)

A fancier solution would be to create a select menu where you can select between the 3 sub commands. Thats how I would do it.